# how to set the rank of highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name **candidateSalary** like

```
+---------------+-----------+
|  candidateID  | Salary    |
+---------------------------+
|  1            | 10000     |
|  2            | 12000     |
|  3            | 8000      |
|  4            | 5000      |
+---------------------------+
```

I just want to write a query to know the rank of my salary. I am trying the RANK() and DENSE_RANK() functions of SQL but not working on mysql.

The output i want is

```
select candidateID,Salary,rank from candidateSalary where candidateID = 2

+---------------+-----------+------+
|  candidateID  | Salary    | rank |
+---------------------------+------+
|  2            | 12000     | 1    |
+---------------------------+------+
```

if candidates rank is not 1 or 2 then rank should be 3 of all other candidate.

Comment: Try with `SELECT *, row_number() over (ordrer by salary desc) AS rnk FROM table`

Comment: MySQL does not provide row_number()

Answer (score 0):

This returns the equivalent of `dense_rank()`:

```
select count(distinct cs.salary)
from candidateSalary cs
where cs.salary >= (select cs2.salary
                    from candidateSalary cs2 
                    where cs2.candidateId = 2
                   );
```

Or if you want this for all candidates:

```
select cs.*,
       (select count(distinct cs.salary)
        from candidateSalary cs2
        where cs2.salary >= c2.salary
       ) as dense_rank
from candidateSalary cs;
```

Comment: The first query result the rank fine but other details are wrong. and second query returns multiple rows.

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma . . . I don't understand  your comment.  What other details in the first query?  It is returning exactly one value.  The second is returning the value for all rows, so naturally it returns multiple rows.

Comment: other details like candidateID and Salary

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma . . . Just add a `where` clause to the second query.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff your query help me to gave idea to wright the right query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below:-

```
select candidateID,MAX(Salary) as sallary,rank from candidateSalary where candidateID = 2
```

Comment: is non valid SQL.. you are mixed a aggregate column with non aggregate columns